# Visual Studio Community 2019 doesn't have "use previews of the .Net Core SDK"

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I installed .net core 3.0 preview 6 SDK on my machine using cmd checked installed version:

[image]

read [this article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/03/08/vs-2019-core-tip.aspx) how to enable .net core 3.0 in visual studio 2019 but i haven't this option:

[image]

i've installed .net core SDK and Runtime, also updated VS, so did i miss anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was moved to another location Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features
[image]